# Is an input field valid while is empty?

Tags: css, html

I've been experimenting with css pseudo classes and pseudo elements and I discover something that I have not been able to get around.

Consider the following html input field:

```
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="1000" step="1" pattern="\d" /><span></span>
```

In order to achieve 3 states: empty, valid and invalid. I'm using the ::after pseudo element (applied to the span  adjacent to the input) to add a checkmark when the value of the filed is valid, and an X when the value is invalid.

I'm using the pseudo classes :valid and :invalid and it seems that when an input field is empty (value="") its state is also valid.

The CSS in question is as follows:

```
.v3_forms input[value=""] + span::after {
    content: "";
}
.v3_forms input:valid + span::after {
    content: "\2713";
    color: limegreen;
}
.v3_forms input:invalid + span::after {
    content: "X";
    color: #ce0000;
}
```

For what I'm able to tell, after clearing the value in the browser, the second css rules takes precedence, even though the specificity is the same.
I tested the selectors here: [specificity calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/) and it seems that attributes and pseudo classes have the same weight.

Comment: I believe it has to be marked with the `required` attribute if you want to disallow empty values. I'd have to review the spec to know for sure, though.

Comment: Yes, and you can see this in action here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/v/valid/

Comment: Re your specificity problems: matching rules of the same specifity are applied in the order in which they occur in the source, i.e. the last rule can overwrite properties of previous rules.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An empty string is, by default, a valid value:

> User agents should allow the user to set the value to the empty
>   string *.

If you want to require a value for the field, you need to add the `required` attribute:

```css
.v3_forms input[value=""] + span::after {
    content: "";
}
.v3_forms input:valid + span::after {
    content: "\2713";
    color: limegreen;
}
.v3_forms input:invalid + span::after {
    content: "X";
    color: #ce0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="v3_forms">
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="1000" step="1" pattern="\d" required /><span></span>
</div>
```

This addresses the specific example in your question, but the same will hold true for any of the `<input />` elements that accept user input.

*See the [whatwg](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29) reference.